# Problem Installing older TestNG plugin on Eclipse 3.5

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I'm trying to install TestNG 5.11 on eclipse 3.5 and gettign the following.

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_19
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=no_NO
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product


Error
Mon Jun 07 15:45:53 CEST 2010
Artifact not found: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.testng.eclipse,5.11.0.28.

java.io.FileNotFoundException:  "http://beust.com/eclipse/features/org.testng.eclipse_5.11.0.28.jar"
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryStatusHelper.checkFileNotFound(RepositoryStatusHelper.java:289)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.checkException(FileReader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:326)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:71)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:127)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:468)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:451)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:518)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:200)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:175)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:159)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:507)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Error
Mon Jun 07 15:45:53 CEST 2010
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse,5.11.0.28.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: "http://beust.com/eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_5.11.0.28.jar"
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryStatusHelper.checkFileNotFound(RepositoryStatusHelper.java:289)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.checkException(FileReader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:326)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:263)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:71)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:127)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:468)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.downloadArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:451)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:518)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:200)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:175)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:159)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:507)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Error
Mon Jun 07 15:45:53 CEST 2010
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
```

I'm kinda stuck so I would really like help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also point your update site to:

http://beust.com/eclipse-5.11.0.28

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [mentioned location](http://beust.com/eclipse/features/) in your browser, you'll see that the old jar you're requesting isn't there anymore. Luckily, you can still download the old version [from the TestNG website](http://testng.org/doc/download.html) and install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It's because [version 5.11.0.28 is not on that server anymore](http://beust.com/eclipse/).

<strike>try org.testng.eclipse_5.12.0.6.jar</strike>

(sorry, part of the question was in the headline, you asked for an older version...)