# Where is the TestNG eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, testng

[Where to find 5.x Testng eclipse plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642925/where-to-find-5-x-testng-eclipse-plugin)

[Problem Installing older TestNG plugin on Eclipse 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995237/problem-installing-older-testng-plugin-on-eclipse-3-5)

Both questions are quite old so the links there do not work anymore. I have Eclipse 3.5 and I would like to install the Eclipse TestNG plugin. What is the location of the update site? I am moving to TestNG so I can move the latest version of TestNG

PS: I have tried http://beust.com/eclipse/ but it throw me an NPE as shown below

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to Install TestNG in Eclipse-Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847549/not-able-to-install-testng-in-eclipse-kepler)

Answer (score 5):

Try to download TestNG plugin from Market Place.

Eclipse - > Help - > Eclipse MarketPlace -> TestNG..

Install it. After restarting Eclipse  use it.

Answer (score 4):

Try the URL that the jar comes from: http://beust.com/eclipse/
Use that above link as the Location, make sure to include the http://.

Comment: That does not work? If I add an update site with that JAR url it fails

Comment: Umm I must be tryign something wrong here. Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software -> New Site -> Put Testng as name and the jar link as the url -> click on show updates -> I get a NPE?

Comment: Name: Testng
Location: http://beust.com/eclipse/

It keeps removing the http://. but make sure to include that before the link in the Location, if not Eclipse will give the error "Location must be absolute".

Comment: Did the comment answer the question correctly?  I went and updated the main answer so people in the future have it simplified so they don't have to read through all the comments.

Comment: The update site has the http correctly. I have added a screen shot explaining my problem?

Comment: What are the details of the error message (expand the "Details >>").  Can you expand that and copy/paste or screen shot them.

I was able to do it just fine using that URL, I am running Eclipse 3.7.2.

Comment: Try and use the a different URL to the most recent version:
http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse-6.7.0.20120808_0858/

Answer (score 3):

I used the latest url posted on the following page http://beust.com/eclipse-old/

That is http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse-6.7.0.20120825_1316/

It worked perfectly fine.

Your URL looks fine (http://beust.com/eclipse) hence I suspect an issue unrelated to this, maybe your Eclipse installation is buggy or incorrectly configured (I did not need any special config on my Eclipse install though).

Comment: This url worked for me, when the main url http://beust.com/eclipse/ installed but didn't add any menu options to eclipse luna. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IN windows how to install testng plugin in Eclipse:

```
1. Open Eclipse
2. Click on Help at top menu
3. Click on Install New Software... sub-menu
4. Click on Add button
Do the following at Add Repository pop-up:
5. Enter name as (Example - testng)
6. Enter URL as your requirement:
   For Eclipse 3.4 and above, enter http://beust.com/eclipse
   For Eclipse 3.3 and below, enter http://beust.com/eclipse1
7. Click on OK button
8. Check process bar is displayed because plugin is installed in eclipse
```

After installation follow the steps below:
i)   Restart eclipse
ii)  Go to Window-> Preferences and observe the left panel
iii) TestNG is enlisted

Answer (score 1):

I noticed it was proxy that was stopping for installation after configuring proxy it installed like cream.

earlier comment:
After a lot of attemp and trying different URL finally found the URL worked for me :  http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse-6.7.0.20120825_1316/

all other URL kept on giving error for MD5 example:
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse,6.9.11.201604020423.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: da03b0c2cd24e2636ad05a151538b195 and found 60ea74539d11470e704c4210de6e5573.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse.maven,6.9.11.201604020423.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 91946a86a2a3ae80d8583be62a9fe068 and found 0f70e9fd8a1bb2564f26bc4730a58922.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: I found lot of people facing issues installing TestNG like me although they have reported different errors but what I found addin provider http://beust.com/ has archived all the old version of this add-in at: http://beust.com/eclipse-old/ and the current version at : http://beust.com/eclipse/ some of the users might have installed current version corrctlly but for those facing any issue i would suggest to try all old version and see which one work for you. one or the other may work for you my vote is for :  http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse-6.7.0.20120825_1316/

Comment: I tried to installing testNG on other workstation and it worked fine using marketplace or using URL. I noticed it is just the proxy which was stopping me in downloading due to some reasons. if you are also facing this issue  please configure proxy in you eclipse first.

Answer (score 0):

if the link: http://beust.com/eclipse/ is not working for versions 3.4 and above, there could be some problem with the Network Connections of your eclipse.
Go to Window->Preferences-> search for SSL or Network Connections.
Check if the settings for the same are in place as per your internet/intranet.

Answer (score 0):

open Eclipse 
CLick on Help at top navigator
Click on install new software
Click on add Button
Add Repository pop-up is open
Enter name as (Example - TestNG)
Enter URL - http://beust.com/eclipse
Click on OK button
Check process bar is displayed because plugin is install in ecplise
After restart the eclipse
Check Testng is install in ecplise

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse Luna - http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse/metrics
Drag and drop the install icon to the eclipse workspace and follow instructions.

Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, looks like updates for Eclipse was the issue.

I just installed the updates to my eclipse (Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600) and restarted Eclipse.
Then, went to help->Eclipse Marketplace-> searched TestNG and Installed it.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The given site "http://beust.com/eclipse" gets redirected to 
http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

because of that eclipse fails to fetch the plugin in the original URL.

to fix that, go to help->install new software
now add new site at work with
"https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/"

it is "https", doing this will list down the plugins available in the URL,

select TestNG, and continue to install it.

it worked for me, hope it works for you as well.